# Can not convert QString to QDateTime

Tags: c++, qt, qdatetime

I have to convert QString to QDateTime by QDateTime::fromString method. I have QString object which contains "Wed, 13 Jun 2018 12:52". But when I use it QDateTime::fromString returns invalid object and I don't knew why. I use "ddd, MM-MMM-yyyy HH:MM" format. Could anyone tell me what I doing wrong?

My code:

```
QString tempDate; //Wed, 13 Jun 2018 12:52
QDateTime::fromString(tempDate, "ddd, MM-MMM-yyyy HH:MM"); //returns invalid obj
```

Comment: Try without the `-`.

Comment: Same result. QDateTime object is still invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your QDateTime format does not correspond to your input string.

`Wed, 13 Jun 2018 12:52` should be matched with `ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm`.

See [QDateTime::fromString](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetime.html#fromString-1).

Also, make sure you're using the correct locale when doing the conversion, as `ddd` and `MMM` are localized. Either change the local with [QLocale::setDefault](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlocale.html#setDefault), or with [QLocale::toDateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50898591/edit):

`QLocale(QLocale::English).toDateTime(tempDate, "ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm");`

Comment: Thank you so much! It really helped.

Answer (score 0):

QDateTime startTime = QDateTime::fromString (QString("1970-07-18T00:00:00"), Qt::ISODate);